# How to write scalable java-ee application

Tags: jakarta-ee, scalability

I am planning to implement a web application with database. Database servers are of the following structure: 1 Master and several Slave servers.
The goal is to make the application scalable, so that if I add and/or remove one more database Slave server - it will keep working without the need in recompilation.

The question is how to make a java EE application independent on the amount of servers? 
Usually I inject the resourses, however in this case this solution won't work, because the amount of servers is not fixed.

What should I read to understand about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

somes articles,

Remember scalability is the father of performance. In fact its goal is  to get high performance.

So your scalabity can be define, in several place :

**Code :** About the Hot Lock for example you should reduce the number of *synchronized blocks,Reducing lock granularity,Avoid lock on static methods*

**Replication issues:** You seem to be aware about it cool, i just suggest one thing p2p system is better  than master-slave also called Primary-Based Replication in this case. Cause you have to ensure the life of the master, master down, you will have to elect new master(bully ?), synchronized database.... !!

**Here some must-know articles about scalability :**

- http://marakana.com/bookshelf/javaee_tutorial/high_availability_and_scalability.html
- http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363681/Scaling-Your-Java-EE-Applications

Hope it's helped.